# WebDriver Get element from elements block

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

> I've tried to get child element from list of elements and instead of
>   return child element value for each item in list -> it returns only
>   first item.

```
List<WebElement> allAccoElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ListerContainer']//li[@class='lister-item']//div[@class='lister-item-content']")); 
// Found 10 items

for (WebElement element: allAccoElements){
System.out.println(element.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class='image-base']")).getAttribute("id")); 
//For loop will print "id" of first element 10 times, why I can't to get access to other Elements in list?
}

Print always return id of first element in list, can anyone suggest me, how I can find child element of each element in list?
```

> Instead, if I use the following code like workaround, all works fine.

```
List<WebElement> allAccoElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ListerContainer']//li[@class='lister-item']//div[@class='lister-item-content']//img[@class='image-base']")); 
// Found 10 items:

for (WebElement element: allAccoElements){
System.out.println(element.getAttribute("id")); 
//Print 10 times with different id
}
```

Comment: That's because you use XPath selector in `findElement` which starts with `/` (it points to the root of the HTML and thus doesn't apply to the context of `element`).

Comment: Indeed, to find corresponding item inside other, we have to workaround it (by adding dot "." before "//" in xpath):

Thank you p0deje for your suggestion!

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to +1 the comment and answer this question so other guys could find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to p0deje we've found the answer:

To find corresponding item inside other, we have to workaround it (by adding dot "." before "//" in xpath).